# Handle the data from SQLite/Android

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

How can I traverse through this set of data?

```
 String[] from = new String[]{AppSQLite.KEY_NAME,AppSQLite.KEY_ICON};
 int[] to = new int[]{R.id.main_menu_list_item);
```

I want to pass them to a custom simple cursor adapter and override getView() so that 
the KEY_NAME is the text (with setText probably) and

```
   setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(**KEY_ICON**, 0, 0, 0);
```

My getView is this:

```
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon_list_item, null);
    }
    this.c.moveToPosition(pos);     
    String name= this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex(AppSQLite.KEY_NAME));
    String icon= this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex(AppSQLite.KEY_ICON));

    TextView mName= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_textView);
    bTitle.setText(name);

    mName.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, 0, 0, 0);
    return v;
```

In my db the icon is in this form:

```
R.drawable.menu_icon TEXT
```

So I think there is another problem with putting the value in `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon parameter is an integer, and not a string. From your code, it seems that you are passing a string, which should give you a compile error.

Update: Store some strings in the database, and write logic to load different drawables.

Store these, icon_1, icon_2, icon_3

```
if(icon_1){
   use R.drawable.icon_1;
else if(icon_2)
   use R.drawable.icon_2;
and so on....
```

Comment: yes i know, and i dont know how to make it work? should i store images in another way or is there any function like eval in js?